# Dynamics AX 2012 R2: Initiate PO approve workflow using a web service, WCF

Tags: wcf, rest, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

We're trying to setup an external service to hook into AX for approving POs, and expenses. This would be through a REST call coming in.

Could someone please guide us to a documentation or what we could look up to get information on this?

Cheers.

Comment: To clarify, at high level we're trying to achieve a business process as follows:

- user is able to retrieve the status of POs assigned to him, pending approvals

- user is then able to approve or reject the PO

- the user action then triggers the respective workflow in AX and follows the escalation / rejection etc process as been configured in AX.

- user is shown new status of PO (which might not be assigned to him)

We're trying to investigate how we can call upon the approval / reject workflow external to AX

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a Visual Studio project and design your restful service as normal, but use proxy classes into your custom x++ logic to interact with workflow classes, another might be to look into AIF